# disable script running from c#/asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Hello I want to disable this script for twitter widget to be displayed on some pages. How can I access the script from the backend and change the url on runtime?

```
<script id="twitter" src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js">
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

That's not really possible.. modern browsers will leave the code in memory even if you remove the script tag from the DOM itself.

The only way around I can think of is to "overwrite" the object/functions: in the bottom of the page have your own script defining exactly the same functions and objects like that script, except they will be null/empty so the final result is like removing the script.